# вк бот не видит сообщения без админки

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот

бот на vk_api не видит подстроку в сообщении и вообще не отправляет сообщения, пока ему не дадут админку.
почему.
мой код:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

TOKEN = ''

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=TOKEN)
svk = vk.get_api()
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, 200617297)

home_work = ''
invisible_pin = ''
name_block = False

def send(message):
    if event.from_chat:  # Для бесед
        svk.messages.send(chat_id=event.chat_id, message=message, random_id=0)
while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            text = event.object['text']
            if 'привет' in text:
                send('ну привет')
```

Comment: Это абсолютно нормально. Большинство пользователей не желают, чтобы всю их переписку мог читать владелец бота. Стандартное поведение предполагает, что боту приходят только сообщения с его упоминанием. Если нужно больше, то Вы вручную должны выдать права на чтение всей переписки или права администратора.

Comment: Да, если читать сообщения нельзя, то почему без администратора вообще сообщения не отправляются?

Comment: PS.раньше все читало и отправляло, а сейчас...

Comment: И к тому же он может считать команду так: if text == '/comand':

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, это вообще не фиксится.